# How do I install third party packages from non-default repositories in Amazon Linux?

Tags: fedora, repository, amazon-linux, amazon-linux-2

My ultimate goal is to create a Docker image with a particular binary installed ([loudgain](https://pkgs.org/search/?q=loudgain)) that I can run functions on.

As above, pkgs.org claims the binary is available from both "fedora-updates" and "RPM Fusion Free" repositories. I've tried manually installing the Fedora Updates `.repo` file into `/etc/yum/repos.d` on Amazon Linux 2, but I get a "not found" error when I try to `yum install loudgain` (is pkgs.org wrong?)

When I try to `dnf install https://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm` on Amazon Linux 2022 I get the error "nothing provides system-release(34) needed by rpmfusion-free-release-34-1.noarch", but I thought Amazon Linux 2022 was based on Fedora 34 so I don't understand why.

I have had no responses [posting](https://repost.aws/questions/QUbWCZvgOCTw-PNocEonzGHQ/how-do-i-install-a-package-from-fedora-updates-on-al-2-or-al-2022) in the [official](https://repost.aws/questions/QUMBedQV49RtOXxsSJSCduVA/how-do-i-install-the-rpm-fusion-repo-on-amazon-linux-2022) AWS forums.

Comment: By hand-editing an `/etc/yum.repos.d/fedora-rawhide.repo` to point to a `BASEURL` of `https://eu.edge.kernel.org/fedora/development/rawhide/Everything/aarch64/os/`, I've managed to get `loudgain` to actually install (yay!) in an Amazon Linux 2 image. But running it gives me "loudgain: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libopenmpt.so.0: undefined symbol: mpg123_param2" (boo!)